# why multiple assignments and single assignments behave differently in python

Tags: python

I was working with queue in python when I had a error in code even while the code looked very perfect to me but latter when I changed assignment style all of sudden the code started working. The code looked some what like this before.

```
    x=y=Queue()
    x.put("a")
    x.put("b")
    print y.get()
```

later i changed to this and it started working

```
    x=Queue()
    y=Queue()
    x.put("a")
    x.put("b")
    print y.get(10)
```

why do both code work differently?

Comment: Because in `x=y=Queue()` `x` and `y` are references to the same object.

Comment: Also, note that `y.get(10)` is probably not what you want.  The first parameter to [`Queue.get()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) is `block`, which is interpreted as a `bool`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Variables in Python are references, or names, not like variables in C etc.

This code:

```
x=y=Queue()
```

means "allow the name `y` to reference an object in memory made by calling `Queue()`, and allow the name `x` to reference the object that `y` is pointing to." This means both variables refer to the same object - as you can verify with `id(x) == id(y)`.

This code:

```
x=Queue()
y=Queue()
```

means "allow the name `x` to reference one object made by `Queue()`, and allow the name `y` to reference another object made by `Queue()`". In this case, `id(x) == id(y)` is `False`

This can often bite you:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a
b.append(6)
print(a)
# [1,2,3,4,5,6] even though we didn't seem to do anything to a!
```

To get around this, do `import copy; b = a.copy();` instead of `b = a`.

However, this behaviour doesn't occur to immutable objects like integers:

```
a = 7
a += 1
```

This *doesn't* go to the object that `a` is referencing and change it by adding one, instead it dereferences `a` from the object 7, and references it to the object representing the previous value of `a` + 1 (that is to say, 8). This is unlike actions performed on mutable objects, like lists in the previous example - appending to a list *does* change the object that the variable is referencing.

So we can do this:

```
a = 7
b = a
a += 1
print(a)
# 8
print(b)
# 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first code is actually equivalent to:

```
y=Queue()
x=y
x.put("a")
x.put("b")
print y.get()
```

Which is different than your second example, because Python handles object by reference. After `x=y` both variables `x` and `y` refer to the same object. In your second example you have two independent queues.