# Python parameters in recursive functions

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement a recursive function to solve a 3-SAT problem as described in the this great Udacity course https://www.udacity.com/course/cs313
I am new of Python programming and I have noticed a behavior I find strange.

The fact is that when the recursive3SatSolver ends returning None and the algorithm backtracks to a new branch the solution variable (passed as parameter at each iteration) is not set to the previous state but remains with the latest value (the one modified within the ended function)

it behaves as if the parameter was passed by reference and not by value

```
def solve_3SAT(num_variables, clauses):
    solution = [-1]*(num_variables+1)
    satisfiedClauses = [0]*len(clauses)
    for i in range(0, num_variables+1):
        positive = False
        negative = False
        for idClause,clause in enumerate(clauses):
            positive = positive or (i in clause)
            negative = negative or (-i in clause)
        candidate = positive ^ negative
        for idClause,clause in enumerate(clauses):
            if i in clause:
                if candidate:
                    satisfiedClauses[idClause]=1
        if candidate:
            if positive:
                solution[i]=1
            else:
                solution[i]=0
    solution[0]=0
    print 'preprocessing: ',solution
    solution = recursive3SatSolver(num_variables,solution,clauses)
    if solution != None:
        for idS,s in enumerate(solution):
            if solution[idS]<0:
                solution[idS]=0
    return solution    

def recursive3SatSolver(num_variables, solution, clauses):
    if is_satisfiable(clauses,solution)==False:
        return None
    satisfiedClauses = satisfied_clauses(clauses,solution)
    for idC,sat in enumerate(satisfiedClauses):
        if sat == 0:
            chosenClause=idC
            clause = clauses[chosenClause]
            for idVar,var in enumerate(clause):
                absVar = abs(var)
                if solution[absVar]<0:
                    value=-1
                    if var>0:
                        value=1
                    else:
                        value=0
                    solution[absVar]=value
                    if is_satisfied(num_variables,clauses,solution):
                        return solution
                    else:
                        finalSolution = recursive3SatSolver(num_variables,solution,clauses)
                        if finalSolution!=None:
                            #print 'returning ...'
                            return finalSolution
                        else:
                            print 'changing branch: ',solution,'=>'
                            solution[absVar]=1-solution[absVar]
                            continue
            print 'finished possibilities for this clause'        
            return None

    if is_satisfied(num_variables,clauses,solution):
        return solution
    else:
        print 'no more clauses'
        return None

def satisfied_clauses(clauses,assignment):
    satisfiedClauses= [0]*len(clauses)
    for idClause,clause in enumerate(clauses):
        if is_clause_satisfied(clause,assignment):
            satisfiedClauses[idClause]=1
    return satisfiedClauses

def is_satisfiable(clauses, assignment):
    for clause in clauses:
        if is_clause_satisfiable(clause,assignment):
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True

def is_clause_satisfiable(clause,assignment):
    sat = is_clause_satisfied(clause,assignment)
    if sat :
        return True
    else:
        for idVar, var in enumerate(clause):
            absVar = abs(var)
            if assignment[absVar]==-1:
                return True
        return False

def is_clause_satisfied(clause,assignment):
    for idVar,var in enumerate(clause):
        absVar = abs(var)
        if assignment[absVar]<0:
            continue
        if var>0:
            if assignment[absVar]==1:
                return True
        else:
            if assignment[absVar]==0:
                return True
    return False

def is_satisfied(num_variables, clauses, assignment):
    if assignment==None:
        return False
    check=True
    for clause in clauses:
        clauseVal = False;
        for var in clause:
            val=False;
            if var<0:
                val = not assignment[abs(var)]
            else:
                val = assignment[var]
            clauseVal = clauseVal or val
        check = check and clauseVal
    return check

def test():
    clauses = [[-2, -3, -1], [3, -2, 1], [-3, 2, 1],
               [2, -3, -1], [3, -2, 1], [3, -2, 1]]
    solutions = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0]]
    assert solve_3SAT(3,clauses) in solutions

    clauses = [[2, 1, 3], [-2, -1, 3], [-2, 3, -1], [-2, -1, 3],
               [2, 3, 1], [-1, 3, -2], [-3, 2, 1], [1, -3, -2],
               [-2, -1, 3], [1, -2, -3], [-2, -1, 3], [-1, -2, -3],
               [3, -2, 1], [2, 1, 3], [-3, -1, 2], [-3, -2, 1],
               [-1, 3, -2], [1, 2, -3], [-3, -1, 2], [2, -1, 3]]
    assert solve_3SAT(3,clauses) == None
    print 'Tests passed'

clauses = [[2, 1, 3], [-2, -1, 3], [-2, 3, -1], [-2, -1, 3],
               [2, 3, 1], [-1, 3, -2], [-3, 2, 1], [1, -3, -2],
               [-2, -1, 3], [1, -2, -3], [-2, -1, 3], [-1, -2, -3],
               [3, -2, 1], [2, 1, 3], [-3, -1, 2], [-3, -2, 1],
               [-1, 3, -2], [1, 2, -3], [-3, -1, 2], [2, -1, 3]]
assert solve_3SAT(3,clauses) == None
print 'Tests passed'
```

**UPDATE**
I have been wondering why I have needed some time to get this. And I have understood the reason is that I was used to program back tracking on boolean clauses/predicates in Prolog where the variables are automatically set to the previous step when a branch fail.

Comment: It behaves like this, because that's exactly what's happening, because that's how Python works.

Comment: Have a look at answers to one of the questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067252/why-multiple-assignments-and-single-assignments-behave-differently-in-python/19067302#19067302), which explain how variables work in Python.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but your question concerns a fairly specific and narrow behavior. I think I see where things go wrong, but could you post a simple example that shows the same behavior? That will make your question easier to understand; it will also make the phenomenon easier to explain; and it will make this a better contribution to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it behaves as if the parameter was passed by reference and not by value

Every object is passed by reference in Python. In your case if `solution` is a list you should probably make a copy of it.

Some methods you can use:

```
>>> l = [0,1,2]
>>> list(l) # creates a new list from the old one
[0, 1, 2]
>>> l[:] # slices also create a new object
[0, 1, 2]
>>> import copy
>>> copy.deepcopy(l) # create a deep copy of the object
[0, 1, 2]
>>> [i for i in l] # manually copy an object
[0, 1, 2]
```

My preferred way is to use the `list(...)` constructor.

Comment: In Python every object is passed _by value_. Even references are passed by value - in this case, a copy of the referenced is passed.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez. If you pass a `mutable` object, the objects reference (id(object)) will be passed by value. This means the object get's passed by reference. It's more a question of syntax, since you can't consider the value of a list being it's reference can you? Especially in a high level language. (Also please see sys.getrefcount)

Comment: Furthermore it isn't actually passing any value, it's actually incrementing the `refcount` of the object and binding it's reference to the new name (variable).

Comment: Please get your concepts right. This has been discussed countless times, to name [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). Python is pass-by-value, like Java. It's just that in the case of objects, the value passed is a reference.

Comment: Here's one interesting article that explains that it's neither pass by reference or by value: http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/  And another stack overflow answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262920/understanding-pythons-call-by-object-style-of-passing-function-arguments

Comment: I get it, I can't see why it is so clear to me in Java while I remained a bit upset in Python. I have just changed to list(solution) and it worked