# Python3, if two variables have the same value, then do they have same address?

Tags: python

In python, fuction id() returns the memory address of the object. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)  and in python, if two variables have the same value, then do they have same address?

```
In [30]: a = 'asdf'

In [31]: hex(id(a))
Out[31]: '0x1082caa08'

In [32]: b = 'asdf'

In [33]: hex(id(b))
Out[33]: '0x1082caa08'

In [34]: c = 2

In [35]: hex(id(c))
Out[35]: '0x1067295c0'

In [36]: d = 2

In [37]: hex(id(d))
Out[37]: '0x1067295c0'
```

Comment: string & integer interning is implementation defined. So yes and no. depends.

Comment: "if two variables have the same value, then do they have same address?" — Sometimes.

Comment: I wouldn't worry for all this `is` and `id` stuff. Leave that to the python coders.

Comment: Just discussed this subject this afternoon, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037548/python-is-operator-behaviour-with-string/50037786?noredirect=1#comment87093207_50037786

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I [do not think it is an exact duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate). It has the same answer, but the question is neither about `is` operator nor exclusively about strings.

Comment: that's why I added several duplicate links. The question is a composite duplicate.

Comment: now if you have a better duplicate to suggest, there's still one slot left :)

Comment: (note that the question doesn't match the snippets. There's no `float` test or lists, or tuples, whatever, which makes the question too broad)