# Simple python string concatenation

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have following test,

```
def test_strings_concatenation(self):
    dict = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    dict_as_string = " ".join(dict)
    expected = 'a b c'
    assert dict_as_string is expected
```

and I want to get `dict` exactly, (*identical to*)  `expected`. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: `assert dict_as_string == expected`. This is not a job for `is`. (Alternately, if you're asking if there's a way to make `is` truthy in this scenario... no.) Also, try not to use variable names that are pre-defined in Python, like `dict`. See [Is there a difference between “==” and “is”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: `is` will check if two object point to the same place in memory. Here `dict_as_string` and `dict` are two separate objects and therefore `is` will return `False`.

Comment: `dict = ['a', 'b', 'c']` is extremely misleading. `dict` is the built-in for _dictionary_

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry for use dict as name.

Comment: @TomaszBartkowiak well I have checked that if I create two different object with the same value it gives me equality. `   def test_strings_comp(self):
        a1='a'
        a2='a'
        assert a1 is a2 `

Comment: @TomaszBartkowiak correct me if I am wrong, but what the OP found is a special behaviour, pointing to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037548/python-is-operator-behaviour-with-string

Comment: @KubaWenta That is because Python caches small integers so they effectively are the same object, e.g for `a = 'a'` and `b = 'a'` `a is b` yields `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, never use pre-defined constants like `dict` as variable names as @Amadan pointed out, also `['a', 'b', 'c']` is a `list`, and not a `dictionary`,  (which is a container to hold key-value pairs e.g. `{"a":"b"}`.

Also you would want to check for `==` since you want the list to be concatenated to a string, and not `is`, since `is` checks if two object refers to the same location of memory as @TomaszBartkowiak pointed out , like below

```
In [21]: a = 1   

In [22]: b = a                                                                                                                                                                    

In [23]: a is b                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[23]: True

In [24]: li = ['a', 'b', 'c']                                                                                                                                                     

In [25]: s = ' '.join(li)                                                                                                                                                         

In [26]: s is li                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[26]: False
```

Hence the code will change to

```
def test_strings_concatenation():
    #Define list and concatenate it
    li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    li_as_string = " ".join(li)
    expected = 'a b c'
    #Check for string equality
    assert li_as_string == expected

test_strings_concatenation()
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, sorry for using dict, I have forget about that it is reserved name. As I said In comment in question, if `is` not allow to compare value, why following test passed? `    def test_strings_comp(self):
        a1='a'
        a2='a'
        assert a1 is a2 `

Comment: It's only for some special cases, read more at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037548/python-is-operator-behaviour-with-string also assert fails if you do `a1='a,'` and `a2='a,'`

Comment: Also look here @KubaWenta http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/ for more details on why this happened

Comment: Does it make sense with the links I posted @KubaWenta ?

Comment: Btw I have test this `'a,'` and it pass for me.

Comment: Even _lorem ipsum_ works when I put it in two diffrent object and compar with `is`.