# 'is' operation in terminal and in Pycharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I am aware of the difference of 'is' operator with strings. However, when I type the following example in Pycharm I get always `True`.

```
a = 'a monkey'
b = 'a monkey'
print(a is b)
```

I get:

```
True
```

Where in terminal:

```
>>> a = 'a monkey'
>>> b = 'a monkey'
>>> a is b
False
```

Why is this happening?

Edit: Why Pycharm returns always True?

Comment: So, you are not "aware of the difference of 'is' operator with strings"? Especially not that you use `==` for string comparison, not `is`.

Comment: I am aware that one should not compare immutable objects with 'is'. My question is why Pycharm always returns True.

Comment: I think the shell is running each line of the input as a separate process - so the interning is not happening. Because when I do this: `a = 'a monkey'; b = 'a monkey'; print(a is b)` I get `True`

Comment: [Bytecode compiler optimization behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35276097/2357112) Never rely on it. It's different in different implementations and subject to change without notice.

Comment: I think, the above could be the answer, which could explain why it behaves differently in `pycharm` and in `shell`. Apologies for the premature answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. New knowledge acquired