# Why does the 'is' operator behave unexpectedly with arithmetically equal expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, identity, equality, cpython

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147515/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-non-cached-integers/39325641#39325641) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275026/python3-multiple-assignment-and-memory-address), I still cannot understand the following behaviour:

```
a = 1000
b = 1000
print (a == b)
print (a is b)
print (f"id(a) = {id(a)} \nid(b) = {id(b)}")
```

As expected I get

```
True
True
id(a) = 2806705928816 
id(b) = 2806705928816
```

But when i try to do something like this:

```
a = 1000
b = 1000 + a - a
print (a == b)
print (a is b)
print (f"id(a) = {id(a)} \nid(b) = {id(b)}")
```

I got `False` in expression `a is b`

```
True
False
id(a) = 3030783801968 
id(b) = 3030783802064
```

Why does a variable behave differently when assigning the result of an expression over a integer and an expression with other variables to it? Although mathematically this gives the same integer.

Comment: Because the two 1000s are literals. They're defined at the onset of the program. There's only one of them needed.

Comment: In the second case, they are not "the same integer"; they are *different* integer objects with the same *value*.

Comment: **what is unexpected exactly**? Why do you *expect* `a is b` to be true here? The fact that this is true in your first example *should be surprising*

Comment: Do not use `is` for checking arithmetic equality, that is what `==` is for. `is` is used to check if two variables/names _reference the same object_.

Comment: This is total speculation, but my guess is that it's just a matter of how smart the compiler optimization is. Most of the time you don't care about how Python is allocating variable memory under the hood, but in the first case, it's doing a little magic to try to save space by avoiding duplicate allocations, all transparent to you if you aren't watching the `id()` values. But in the second case it's not quite smart enough so you end up with 2 allocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do something like :

(case-1)

```
a = 1000
b = a
```

or (case-2)

```
a = 1000
b = 1000
```

Python is smart enough to know before hand that even after execution you won't need new memory.

So, python just before execution makes `b` an alias of `a` in the first case.

The second case is bit different.
Python is a true object oriented language, the literal `1000` is treated as an object. (Intuitively you can think as 1000 to be name of a const object).

So in second case `a` and `b` are technically, both becoming `alias` of `1000`

Now in your example:

```
a = 1000
b = 1000 + a - a
print (a == b)
print (a is b)
```

while assignment of `b`, python doesn't know before hand what is going to be the value of `a`. When I say before-hand I mean before any form of calculation being started. So python reserves a new memory location for `b`and then saves the output of the operation in this new memory location.

It is also worth noting this:

```
4-1 is 3
True
```

In this case, python doesn't saves this line with `4-1` but processes it before compilation to be `3`, for runtime optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a few accurate answers.  Here I am giving a "back to basics" answer.

---

## What is `==`?

Python `==` means *is the value on the left the same as the value on the right*.

```py
sum([5, 7]) == (48 * 3)**0.5
```

is `True`.  It requires several evaluation steps to make each expression reach the value of `12`.  Even then, the *integer* `12` is being compared to the *float* `12.0`, so a final conversion of the integer to a float is necessary.

The key takeaway: each *expression* is *evaluated* and the resulting *values* are compared.  If they are equal, then the expression is true.

## What is `is`?

Python `is`, on the other hand, means *is the name on the left pointing to the same object as the name on the right*.

```py
a = 3.14159
b = a
a is b
```

is `True`. `a` has been assigned to the value `3.14159`. But more to the point, there is a block of memory holding an object, which in this case is the float 3.14159. `a` points to that object / block of memory.  `b` points to `a`, which means that it points to *that same block of memory*.

---

You can very easily test this:  create two "names" that simply point to a number, and compare them using `is`, and they will not match:

```py
>>> a = 1239481203948
>>> b = 1239481203948
>>> a is b
False
```

This is false because we now have two different *locations in memory / objects* pointing to each of them:

```py
>>> id(a)
140402381635344
>>> id(b)
140402391174416
```

(On your machine, you will get a different set of [`id`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).)

So, in effect, you have "wasted" space because you have two objects taking up space for the same information.

## But wait, there's more

If you play around with this on your own, you will find *tons* of exceptions to what I wrote, and confuse yourself.  Here are just a few:

```py
>>> a = 157
>>> b = 157
>>> a is b
True
```

What??  Why is this true?  To optimize Python, the "most common numbers" have been optimized.  I may be wrong, but I recall that there is designated space in memory for the most common numbers.  And those are the first few hundred integers, and a few others.

But there are other optimizations, too:

```py
>>> a = None
>>> b = None
>>> a is b
True

>>> a = True
>>> b = True
>>> a is b
True
```

These are all still following the same rule as I stated earlier:  the reason why `is` evaluates to `True` is because `a` and `b` are both pointing to the same location in memory / object.

This happens in these odd cases because of optimizations in Python. **But generically speaking, the only way to ensure `is` evaluates to `True` is if a name is assigned to an object that already has a name**, like when we wrote:

```py
>>> a = 3.14159
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
```

instead of writing

```py
>>> a = 3.14159
>>> b = 3.14159
>>> a is b
False
```

Answer (score 0):

the difference is in the reference to location.
'==' checks for equality in terms of data type and value however, 'is; reference the location of variable in memory.

is will return false for the below

```
id(a) = 3030783801968 <----
id(b) = 3030783802064 <----
```

is will return true for the below

```
    id(a) = 2806705928816 <----
    id(b) = 2806705928816 <----
```

Comment: I may be confused, but I think the question is made with a correct understanding of the difference between `==` and `is`. The question is why Python assigns the same id/address in one case and not in the other.

Comment: in the second instance, you made 'additional arithmetics by adding 'a-a' thus, python then stores the value in another location

Answer (score 0):

Python executes a statement by evaluating its expressions to values one by one, then performing some operation on those values.

Source:
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/eval_rules.pdf

Basically b = 1000 + a - a is not being done in one go, but in multiple evaluations and python stores the results for b at each evaluation in a different memory location than a. At this point a and b are different objects.

use == for equality checks.

use "is" to check if objects are same (variables are referencing same memory location).